# ADF fails validation over weekend

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Over the weekend, our ADF solution cannot validate any more.

[image: Validation failed]

Error message at validation:

> DF_Postcode Could not load resource 'DF_Postcode'. Please ensure no
> mistakes in the JSON and that referenced resources exist. Status:
> UnknownError, Possible reason: undefined

This includes triggers, pipelines, and dataflows.

[image: Error opening main pipeline]

We did not do any deployments between Friday and this morning. Any thoughts?

-- Update --

Possibly related, starting a data flow debug is not succesful.
[image: Failed to setup debug session]

-- Update 2 --
Multiple pop-ups appear when doing a shift+F5 refresh of the page. The error message itself is not very helpful.

[image: Loading of type dataset has failed]

[image: Loading of type trigger has failed]

Comment: Have you actually checked that the resources being referenced still exist and are accessible by your pipeline?  Just because you did no Data Factory deployments over the weekend doesn't mean something didn't happen to one of the referenced resources.  As an example, are you using a now expired access key?

Comment: Yes, actually some are not there anymore. However, with a page refresh they suddenly appear again. Now another set of datasets has disappeared, impacting different pipelines.

Comment: *Yes, actually some are not there anymore.* - I don't mean have you checked from within Data Factory, I mean have you actually checked the resources themselves?  If you are connecting via Managed Identity, are the resources still configured with the right Role(s) for that Managed Identity?  If you are connecting via Keys, are the Keys still valid etc?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my own answer. It was a failing backend service that caused the random errors. That is why some datasets / pipelines were missing during the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Service Blade in the Azure Portal I found an emerging issue listed.

> Starting at 09:00 UTC, customers may experience errors using Azure
> Data Factory in West Europe, using the Azure Portal UX. We are aware
> of the issue and are investigating. Updates to follow in 60 minutes or
> as events warrant. Workaround: Customers can manage Data Factory using
> Azure Data Studio, Azure CLI or Powershell.
> https://aka.ms/azuredatastudio

[image: Emerging issue ADF]

-- Update from Microsoft --

> Summary of impact: Between approximately 06:30 UTC and 12:30 UTC on 13 Dec 2021, you were identified as a
> customer using Data Factory V2 in West Europe who may have experienced intermittent errors when accessing
> resources in this region.
>
> Preliminary Root Cause: We determined a backend service, responsible for processing API requests became
> unhealthy. This led to intermittent API failing calls for Azure Data Factory resources.
>
> Mitigation: We restarted the backend service which mitigated the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does appear there were few changes pushed to ADF over the weekend. However, as the error says, could you check the resources if they are intact or if any properties or values got reset! just in case to be sure to remove user configuration issue.

Check in the ADF studio for all the resources referenced in the error.

[image]

If you are using Powershell modules at any point in there, make sure you use the latest one.

Also, for quick check you can raise an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new) to get an official response.